# Typescript casting issue with enum map

Tags: typescript, casting

I have the following typescript model:

```
enum Metric {
    COLOR = 'COLOR',
    SIZE = 'SIZE'
};

interface Stats {
    id: number;
    metrics: {[key: number]: {[metricKey in Metric]?: number }};
}
```

I try to cast some objects to `Stats` :

```
const ok = {
    id: 10
} as Stats;

const notOk = {
    metrics: {
        0: {
            [Metric.COLOR]: 10
        }
    }
} as Stats;
```

I do not understand why the first one is ok but not the second one.
It triggers *TS2352  to type 'Stats' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.*

And If possible I would like to not use `as unknown as Stats`

Here a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAssAuAnAlgYygbwFBV1AwgPIAyhASlALxQDkRpZNANDngMoCSAWgKJW2deNLAF8A3FizIQ8YIgBmAQ1TAobeIvgBnTK1zIAJgC4o4CACM5EvFAgIUqLSYwBtANbAAnibOXEAXWcXOyQ0AGkvKGlYezR-AH4fSD8oEXFRSVQAexAteCgst35sG0MTAEYABlEoRR11TS0JLGzc-JAs+EIi6hK8EIcnXRsbSuc9EZsXOFDUADp6ckCoKombEQmNkVr6jW0xIA)

Answer (score 0):

The member `id` ia missing in `notOk`. This code works:

```js
enum Metric {
    COLOR = 'COLOR',
    SIZE = 'SIZE'
};

interface Stats {
    id: number;
    metrics: {[key: number]: {[metricKey in Metric]?: number }};
}

const ok = {
    id: 10
} as Stats;

const notOk = {
    id: 1,
    metrics: {
        0: {
            [Metric.COLOR]: 10
        }
    }
} as Stats;
```

Comment: Ok but why is it working in ok (missing metrics) then? Shouldn't it work the same way?

Comment: That's because you used a cast instead of a type specifier. Remove the cast from `ok`  and write it as `const ok: Stat ...`. That will give you the expected error about `metrics`.

Comment: Ok, but it does not answer the question. Why do we have 2 different behaviors when casting with missing properties?

Comment: It's no different behavior. In both cases the `metrics`  member was ignored. The first case succeeded, because `id` was there, which was not the case for the second part.

Comment: But why in the second case it didn't ignore `id` as it did ignore `metrics` in the first case?